# HTTP load balancing behavior

Tags: tomcat, architecture, load-balancing

I am trying to understand the system behavior of such a setup in case of application server failure:

- hardware load balancer in front of two tomcat servers that host a web application
- load balancer stickyness active
- two tomcats configured either with persistent session manager or in cluster

My understanding is that if one of the two tomcats crashes when serving a request, the user gets an http error message and when he tries refresh the page the balancer redirects the user to the working tomcat which will start processing the request again.

Is this correct and there is no way to avoid that users get error messages when the server that is processing a requests fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour depends on how the load-balancer is configured, the error that you're getting from the tomcat server and the behaviour of your application.

A load-balancer will health-check the servers it is monitoring periodically (every few seconds); so it is entirely possible for a single server to crash between user requests and get noticed by the load-balancer.  That server is then taken out of the group and when the user next refreshes they are directed to one of the remaining servers with no idea that anything has gone wrong in the middle.

This depends on your application being stateless however.  If any state is being stored on the single server (which is implied by use of sticky sessions), then when the user redirects to another server they may get a session timeout or other error and have to relogin and start again.  So step 1 to avoiding users getting errors is to make the application stateless or share state effectively in some manner.

It's also worth considering how the application fails and if the load-balancer will detect it.  Typically load-balancers are configured for either layer 4 or layer 7 healthchecking.

Layer 4 checks that the webserver is listening on a given port (e.g. port 80).  As long as that it responding the server is kept in group.  This is fine for server up / down type monitoring but you can have situations where your application is errored or frozen but the webserver is responding on port 80 and users are still being directed to it.

Layer 7 checks a given piece of content on a webpage that it is configured to monitor.  This is much more 'real world' monitoring as it is looking at the same kind of content that a user is, and will take the server out of group for an application level problem.

Comment: Ok everything is clear in your answer my doubt still remains though. Suppose that we have a load balancer working at layer 7 with proper health checks of the backend servers setup. Backend servers are working and a request is routed to backend 1. Now the backend server starts working the request and when it is working the request something happens and the server crashes. In this situation I think that the user will get the error message and there is not way to avoid this. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes if the crash happens while a request is being processed, there will be an error for that request. Depending on how your application is configured, what happens next will vary. If stateless, then they refresh, they go to the good server, and carry on.  If stateful, then their session data is lost and they will likely need to relogon, etc.